# Why is i(inifinity) equal to 21 A

Tags: circuit-analysis

Image is from Fundamentals of Electric Circuits 6th Edition, Alexander and Sadiku. Page 314.

[image]

```
a) i(0+) = 42/(10+2) = 3.5 A
   v(0+) = (10/12)*42 = 35 V

b) di(0+)/dt = v/L = 35/0.4 = 87.5 A/s
   dv(0+)/dt = ic(0+)/C = 0 V/s

c) v(infinity) = 42 V
   i(infinity) = 42/12 = 3.5 A
```

From my understanding when `t-> infinity` the circuit still remains in the dc steady state, right? Shouldn't the i(infinity) be 3.5A instead of 21A?

Comment: Your understanding is correct, but don't forget that the switch, when closed, bypasses the 10-Ohm resistor altogether. How much resistance remains in the steady state?

Comment: I was actually wondering that but from textbooks like these, is the switch connected to the other end of the 10 ohm resistor? I actually thought it wasn't. Normally wouldn't a dot be present to symbolise its connected to both that and the ground? Since it does bypass it, it's just 2 ohms, wow.

Comment: Most of us, and the built-in schematic editor, would draw a dot on all three junctions in that diagram. This is the uglier style where you'd use a little hoop where wires cross but don't join.

Comment: Either method (ie the dot or little hoop) shouldn't be drawn to have a cross type junction if only to just to avoid this problem. It's a bit rich to have the 6th edition still have stuff like this in it drawn by some graphic artist who's either not a draftperson or engineer.

Comment: I thought the same thing honestly, but i guess somewhere down the line... things just happen. A student of the author told me on reddit, the textbook still has typos everywhere so i was just confused if it was connected seeing as there was neither the hoop nor the dot. Thanks a lot you guys! I appreciate the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At infinity, the switch is closed and steady state has been reached.  Thus the inductor behaves as a short and the capacitor behaves as an open.  The current is only determined by the power source (42 volts) and the circuit resistance (2 ohms).  The current is then 42/2 or 21 amperes.  This is the answer given in the book (under the schematic for question (c)). Don't forget that the switch remains closed after time 0.

Comment: Apart from that though, it appears that the wire the switch is connected to is also connected to the other end of the resistor. That was the reason why I was having a difficult time figuring it out. I was always doing `42/(10+2)` for calculating the current.